# Spinner Small Size

Tags: android, eclipse, spinner

I have a spinner with data content, but the spinner is very small. How can i put the spinner diferrent?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I guess you're talking about the "drop down" item list (in the other case you would just have to change the size of the Spinner in the xml file).

You have differents way to set the Adapter actually, for example, when you declared your ArrayAdapter (or another Adapter), you can set a layout to put data in a View.

[See Android.R.layout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.layout.html)

For example : "simple_spinner_item" is really small so you'd rather use another one like "simple_dropdown_item_1line"

```
  ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,   
  android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,spinnerArray);
```

Can you show us some code if this is not what you are looking for ? I'm not sure of what you are talking (if it's the Spinner element or the list)